# IMacro Error : SyntaxError: wrong format of CMDLINE command, line: 5 (Error code: -910)

Tags: imacros

```
TAB T=1     

TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS  

CMDLINE !DATASOURCE SET !DATASOURCE C:\users.csv

SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1

'Start at line 2 to skip the header in the file

SET !LOOP 2

'Increase the current position in the file with each loop 

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

' Fill web form   

URL GOTO=http://mginger.com/signup.html?inviteId=836485    

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:signupForm ATTR=NAME:firstNameField CONTENT={{!COL1}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:signupForm ATTR=NAME:lastNameField CONTENT={{!COL2}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:signupForm ATTR=NAME:emailField CONTENT={{!COL3}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:signupForm ATTR=NAME:mobileNumberField CONTENT={{!COL4}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:signupForm ATTR=NAME:usernameField CONTENT={{!COL5}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:signupForm ATTR=NAME:passwordField CONTENT={{!COL6}}
```

The error is this

```
IMacro Error : SyntaxError: wrong format of CMDLINE command, line: 5 (Error code: -910)
```

Comment: You have an error, what are you doing to solve the error?  How much experience do you have with iMacros?

Answer (score 1):

Not use **CMDLINE** and **SET** in same line.
Look your line 5